# Sets with an infinite number of {{{...}}}

Tags: set-theory

In pure mathematics, is there such a set with an infinite number of {{{...}}}? Is there a name for them? What are their properties? Letting $$R=\{x∶x\notin x\},$$ does Russell's paradox hold for this sort of sets, {{{...}}}?

Comment: Russell's paradox has nothing to do with what other sets are allowed to exist; it uses only the existence of the set $R$ (and the meaning of set-builder notation).

Comment: Well, the von Neumann ordinal interpretation of $\omega = \aleph_0 = \mathbb{N}$ comes to mind.  On the other hand, if you're using a set theory with the foundation axiom, then that implies any set with such a property would have to have some infinite set in its transitive closure.

Comment: The "letting $R=\{x:x\notin x\}$" part seems like like a nonsequitur, and I'm not sure what it would mean for Russell's paradox to hold for a sort of sets. Sets with infinitely deep nestings of brackets (or more precisely, infinite descending membership chains) are called non-well-founded sets. Their existence is consistent with ZF - foundation, so they don't lead to paradoxes a la Russell. But the axiom of foundation rules them out by design.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) implies there is no infinite descending sequence of sets, so the answer to your infinite curly brace question is "no".

Comment: This is sometimes called the Axiom of Foundation.